# Microsoft Access 2010 VB Script and Query

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, vba

I am doing a report in MS Access, and I want to use VB Script to filter some of my data, but I have never used it before. I have a table (query) that I would like to return the customers who have made ALL of their orders online. I’ve tried different combination, where I set if ID is same to add the price for ONLY customers who have made all of their orders online. I am failing miserably. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I’ve created a replica of the table in JSFiddle. For instance, when it is done the report will only have the following customers: John Smith, Irene François, William Gedeon, and Joshua Gonzalez, since they are the customers who have made all of their orders online for the month of March. Please see the link below for a better understand of the data. Thank you very much.

```
<table  border="1">
    <tr>
        <th width="120">Month/Year</th>
        <th width="120">Customer ID</th>
        <th width="120">Last Name</th>
        <th width="120">First Name</th>
        <th width="120">In/Out of State</th>
        <th width="120">Customer Type</th>
        <th width="120">Product Name</th>
        <th width="120">Source of Order</th>
        <th width="120">Price</th>
        <th width="120">Monthly Total</th>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>000357321</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Natural Olive Oil</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$3</td>
        <td>$7</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>000357321</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Cream of Coconut</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$7</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>   
        <td>000568354</td>
        <td>Purkiss</td>
        <td>Andre</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Pink Candy</td>
        <td>In-Store</td>
        <td>$7</td>
        <td>$17</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>000568354</td>
        <td>Purkiss</td>
        <td>Andre</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Organic Pasta</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$17</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>   
        <td>000568354</td>
        <td>Purkiss</td>
        <td>Andre</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Challah Bread</td>
        <td>Phone Order</td>
        <td>$6</td>
        <td>$17</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>025999248</td>
        <td>François</td>
        <td>Irene</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Bottle Opener</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$8</td>
        <td>$21</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>025999248</td>
        <td>François</td>
        <td>Irene</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Key Chain</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$21</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>   
        <td>025999248</td>
        <td>François</td>
        <td>Irenee</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Printing Paper</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$5</td>
        <td>$21</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>025999248</td>
        <td>François</td>
        <td>Irene</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Cho. Chip Cookies</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$21</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>091357456</td>
        <td>Abramovitch</td>
        <td>Tayron</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Phone Order</td>
        <td>$3</td>
        <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>091357456</td>
        <td>Abramovitch</td>
        <td>Tayron</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Fried Onions</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$7</td>
        <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>   
        <td>022864295</td>
        <td>Hatchner</td>
        <td>Emily</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Vodka Sauce</td>
        <td>In-Store</td>
        <td>$5</td>
        <td>$34</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>   
        <td>022864295</td>
        <td>Hatchner</td>
        <td>Emily</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Old Cheese</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$8</td>
        <td>$34</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>   
        <td>022864295</td>
        <td>Hatchner</td>
        <td>Emily</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Tomatoes</td>
        <td>Phone Order</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$34</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>022864295</td>
        <td>Hatchner</td>
        <td>Emily</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Frying Pan</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$17</td>
        <td>$34</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>092456753</td>
        <td>Gedeon</td>
        <td>William</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>USB Drive</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$2</td>
        <td>$13</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>March/2013</td>  
        <td>092456753</td>
        <td>Gedeon</td>
        <td>Williame</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Cordless Keyboard</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$13</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>092456753</td>
        <td>Gedeon</td>
        <td>William</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>MacBook Charger</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$7</td>
        <td>$13</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>000320680</td>
        <td>Baltar</td>
        <td>D'Anna</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Pineapple</td>
        <td>In-Store</td>
        <td>$3</td>
        <td>$5</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>000320680</td>
        <td>Baltar</td>
        <td>D'Anna</td>
        <td>Non-Resident</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Fresh Fish</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$2</td>
        <td>$5</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>04400250</td>
        <td>Gonzalez</td>
        <td>Joshua</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>NotePad</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$5</td>
        <td>$19</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>04400250</td>
        <td>Gonzalez</td>
        <td>Joshua</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Plastic Binder</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$19</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>04400250</td>
        <td>Gonzalez</td>
        <td>Joshua</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Box of Pencils</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$19</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>March/2013</td> 
        <td>04400250</td>
        <td>Gonzalez</td>
        <td>Joshua</td>
        <td>Resident</td>
        <td>VIP</td>
        <td>Au. Picture Frame</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>$6</td>
        <td>$19</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

JSFiddle Link: "http://jsfiddle.net/xqmDE/29/"

Best,

ZDM

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VB script to do this (although you can use it if you want - see below).

*NOTE: I have presumed a table name of 'Orders' and fields of 'CustomerID' and 'SourceOfOrder'.*

Apply the following in the 'Filter' property of the report, and make sure both the 'Filter On Load' and 'Allow Filters' properties are set to 'Yes'

```
CustomerID IN (
    (SELECT CustomerID FROM
        (SELECT CustomerID, SourceOfOrder
             FROM Orders
             GROUP BY CustomerID, SourceOfOrder
         ) orders_grouped
        GROUP BY CustomerID
        HAVING Count(SourceOfOrder) = 1)
) AND SourceOfOrder = 'Online'
```

If you want to do it in VBA put the following:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Reports!Orders.Filter = "CustomerID IN ((SELECT CustomerID FROM (SELECT CustomerID, SourceOfOrder FROM Orders GROUP BY CustomerID, SourceOfOrder) orders_grouped GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING Count(SourceOfOrder) = 1)) AND SourceOfOrder = 'Online'"
    Reports!Orders.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```